# Node only sends html content to the client instead of sending a whole Vue app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I created a new vue project with the CLI and want to deploy it. Based on this documentation

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode

I added the history mode to the router. After running `npm run build` I took the example code for a static native Node server

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const httpPort = 3000

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('../base/index.html', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    })

    res.end(content)
  })
}).listen(httpPort, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
})
```

So when navigating to `localhost:3000` the vue project seems to load correctly

[image]

but I have a blank page with two errors

[image]

When I click on those js files it shows me the content of the index.html file. Obviously js is not able to understand this html content. How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server will not send the whole vue app at once.

- Browser get html file from server, when you browse to that url.
- Browser parse the html file.
- Browser detects assets (js, images, css).
- Browser request those files.

It request those file from server, but  you haven't initialized  server to find those files.

So, need to add static files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

You can take reference from [here](https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/)

Answer (score 2):

as @Sukul answer before, you just need to server the static files because you have now only one handler to server all the request coming with the HTML file (the mount point document) and when its requesting the *.js app it's expecting the valid javascript syntax instead it finds HTML, and that what the error messages are on the network tab

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const nStatic = require('node-static');
var fileServer = new nStatic.Server('./public');

const httpPort = 3000

const controllers = (req,res)=>{
  if(req.url.includes(".")
   return fileServer.serve(req, res);
  else
  fs.readFile('../base/index.html', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    })

    res.end(content)
  })
}
}

http.createServer(controllers).listen(httpPort, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
})
```

[node-static ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static)

however, I highly recommend you trying to use express.js